# NSMutableArray index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am messing up with JSON and NSMutablearray. Of course I am a beginner.

I have this code, taken and modified for my purposes from an online tutorial:

```
[This is the .m file]
- (void) downloadItems {

    // Download the json file
    NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/service.php"];

    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

    // Create the NSURLConnection
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // Initialize the data object
    datiScaricati = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the newly downloaded data
    [datiScaricati appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    // Create an array to store the locations
    NSMutableArray *frasiMemorizzate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parse the JSON that came in
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datiScaricati options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];


    // Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
        Frase *nuovaFrase = [[Frase alloc] init];
        nuovaFrase.fraseDelDatabase = jsonElement[@"Frase"];

        NSLog(@"Phrase read from database: %@", nuovaFrase.fraseDelDatabase);

        // Add this question to the locations array
        [frasiMemorizzate addObject:nuovaFrase.fraseDelDatabase];

        NSLog(@"Phrases stored in the array: %@", frasiMemorizzate);


        prova = [frasiMemorizzate objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"Phrases at index 0: %@",prova);

    }


}
```

NSLog gives this:

```
2014-06-15 11:05:28.705 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrase read from database: Frase uno, Prova!
2014-06-15 11:05:28.706 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrases stored in the array: (
    "Frase uno, Prova!"
)
2014-06-15 11:05:28.706 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrases at index 0: Frase uno, Prova!
2014-06-15 11:05:28.707 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrase read from database: Frase due, Prova!
2014-06-15 11:05:28.707 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrases stored in the array: (
    "Frase uno, Prova!",
    "Frase due, Prova!"
)
2014-06-15 11:05:28.708 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrases at index 0: Frase uno, Prova!
2014-06-15 11:05:28.708 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrase read from database: Frase tre, Prova!!
2014-06-15 11:05:28.709 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrases stored in the array: (
    "Frase uno, Prova!",
    "Frase due, Prova!",
    "Frase tre, Prova!!"
)
2014-06-15 11:05:28.709 ProvaMySql[13805:60b] Phrases at index 0: Frase uno, Prova!
```

So, I think that I am getting data one by one from database ("frase uno", then "frase due", then "frase tre"). And I see also that the array is populating (Phrased stored in the array:)

When I am calling

```
prova = [frasiMemorizzate objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"Phrases at index 0: %@",prova);
```

I get: "Frase uno", that is what I should expect, but if I use "objectAtIndex:1" I have that error: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0], but I expected to have the second phrase: "Frase Due".

I'd like to know why and the right way to get the data I need, and, maybe, as you are replying my question, how can I Know how many items are stored in a Mutable Array, to non call unallocated index position!

Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is thrown because you try to access second index in the array when there is only one object.

Make this little change and it works:

```
    prova = [frasiMemorizzate objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"Phrases at index %d: %@", i, prova);
```

Comment: Thanks Juniperi, Yes, now It works! But what if I need to pick just one of the three phrases? I thought in the array were stored all the three phrases and then pick the one I need!

Comment: @Funesto you can pick any object you want after that for loop. Your for loop is putting one object to array per round, so you can't access second object on first round.

Comment: -_- Thank you very very much. I am non only a Beginner, I am also stupid!! Now It works. Thanks for your teaching! Now I'll search how to know how many index are in a Mutable Array!

Comment: @Funesto NSUInteger objectCount = [frasiMemorizzate count]; returns that count...